# "This website uses cookies" notices should be hardcoded on the browser instead of the website?

Tags: usability, notification, warnings, cookies

Everyone is annoyed by this virtually useless cookie notices scattered in majority of all websites.

Should there be a new a standard that this notice be placed in the browser instead of the website? From a UX perspective, I think it is the browser's job to "protect" its user from these evil cookies.

Clicking that X button from the "we use cookies" message won't change a thing for non-tech savvy users as they are clueless on how to disable cookies even if they wanted to.

Comment: I guess this is not for this website but yes it would improve UX to have a browser standard to manage this

Comment: I agree with Leths in the comments. Though this isn't a matter for UX.SE, it would make it a great deal easier for website developers, designers and owners.

Comment: This is more of a discussion topic, not an actual problem that you need a solution to.

Comment: The idea is quite old, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P - this kind of protocol would allow the user to declare their privacy preferences once and for all websites. But nobody cared to make it useful and mandatory and then our clueless drones from EU reinvented it in a worst possible way and polluted the whole internet with cookie popups.

Comment: I agree with Leths, but this is a UX challenge too. Browsers have an icon to show that a website is HTTPS, so it's just a matter of figuring out how and where on a browser to unintrusively display the cookies notification instead of having a popup. Is there anyone on the GDPR committee we could contact to notify them that we want a better UX?